# How do I git clone to Windows using different username than I am logged in to Windows with

Tags: git, talend, tortoisegit

I am using Tortoise Git on Windows to clone a remote Git repository on Bitbucket.

I am also using Talend Open Studio (TOS) which only really likes a single login, meaning there are internal properties on objects that change when the user is changed. Since we have multiple users doing development, we all use a single user id to run TOS which effectively eliminates the corruption we were seeing when we were trying to do it with our own user profiles. Unfortunately that makes it harder to export from TOS to the Git working copy.

When I create my local repository, the directories on Windows are set up to only allow me or an administrator to have write permissions on the directories. When I try to export the Talend model to the working copy, it fails because TOS is being run using the common user id.

All that to ask this. How can I run the git clone operation under Tortoise (or even WinGit, I have that installed as well) using the common username that I am using to run TOS?

Note, I am not asking how to log in to Bitbucket using a specific user id, but how to run TortoiseGit on Windows using a different user id.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably need to open an instance of explorer or the command-prompt that's running in the context of the other user and use that for all of your interactions with the repo.

The `Secondary Logon` service must be running on your system.

Then, from a command-prompt or the windows run-box run the following command:

```
runas /user:that-other-user-account "cmd"

# or

runas /user:that-other-user-account "explorer"
```

That new window now runs in the context of the other user.

See also:

- http://woshub.com/run-program-as-different-user-windows

Comment: This seems it should work except I have authority issues doing this. I will try to get those worked out through my IT staff.